# Is there a short proof of the existence of $a$ so that $a$ is a primitive root for infinitely many primes $p$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, cyclic-groups

After looking for a general answer I found Artins conjecture, and I was happy to see so much is known.

However I don't know nearly enough to follow the proof, yet it bothers me I can't prove the existence of any such a.

Is there a elementary/short proof of the existence of one such $a$?

Comment: Thomas Andrews I saw that but the proof is supposedly hard, and I'd love to understand a proof of the existence of such $a$.

Comment: My comment wasn't intended for you, but as a response to a now-deleted comment from another user who thought you were asking about Artin's full conjecture.